# How can I align an image next to an h2?

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

Maybe the tech stack doesn't matter here, but I have a nextjs project with tailwind for styling. I'm trying to insert an image next to an h2 tag, but the image won't behave how I expect it to. There is no vertical overlap, it's like the image is taking up a row, and the text is taking up another row. Here's what I have right now:

[image: image not behaving]

And the code that generated it:

```html
 <div className="pb-3 justify-center align-center">
                <Image
                    src={logoNextjs}
                    alt="logo nextjs"
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                />
                <div>
                    <h2 className="text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl text-center">
                        Sample
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <p className="text-center pb-1 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 lg:text-xl sm:px-16 xl:px-48 ">
                    Demo
                </p>
            </div>
```

If I add a `float-left` class from tailwind to nextjs's `Image` tag, I can get the image and h2 to be somewhat vertically aligned (at least they have some vertical overlap):

[image: some vertical overlap when adding float]

But the problem remains that the image is way to the left, when I want it to be right next to the text.

From what I understand, `Image` is basically an `img` tag with some optimization, so I think plain css solutions will work.

How can I achieve the behavior of the image being fully vertically aligned with the text, and right next to it?

Comment: Put a wrapper element around it to which you apply `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;` (note: in this case the `h2` and its "subtext" `p` should also be in a wrapper)

Comment: @Johannes I had to do justify-content:center, but the flex and align-center worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a flex-box with `justify-content: center`:

```
<div className="flex flex-col pb-3 justify-center align-center">
  <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-full">
    <Image
      className="flex justify-center items-center w-[10rem]"
      src={
        "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/4a/2b/e7/4a2be73b1e2efb44355436c40bf496dd.jpg"
      }
      alt="logo nextjs"
      width={100}
      height={100}
    />
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2 className="text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl text-center">
      Centralized Image
    </h2>
  </div>
  <p className="text-center pb-1 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 lg:text-xl sm:px-16 xl:px-48 ">
    Demo
  </p>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> plain css solutions will work.

Standard positioning approaches include:

- *floats* - a bit anachronistic
- *css tables* - not very well known
- *css grid* - might be overkill

and...

- *flexbox* - probably the best-fit-solution for this situation

---

**Working Example:**

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 24px;
  height: 124px;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

h2, p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="" alt="logo nextjs" />
  <div>
    <h2>Sample</h2>
    <p>Demo</p>
  </div>  
</header>
```

---

**Learn Flexbox:**

- https://flexboxfroggy.com/

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yeah but he is using Tailwind, so it would be better for him to stick around with Tailwind rather than adding external CSS. Great suggestion though

Comment: Thanks. And you make a fair point. But, while I can accept that Tailwind is popular, I have the persistent impression (from everything I've seen of Tailwind) that, instead of helping one learn CSS, there is a danger that Tailwind leaves one caught in the loop of endlessly learning... Tailwind. That time could be spent learning core CSS. (I have a similar take on jQuery and core JS.)

Comment: That's a good insight, it's always better and recommended to go to things like Tailwind after properly grasping CSS, and the same for other things...

Comment: Yes - that's a good summary / rule-of-thumb: learn the core first and then the library / framework - rather than learning the latter as a shortcut and then never learning the fundamentals of the former.

Comment: Words of the wise

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, your code is working correctly except that you have two mistakes:

1. The wrapper `div` missing `flex` class.
2. `p` tag must be beneath `h2` inside th `div`.

That's it!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="pb-3 flex justify-center align-center">
  <img
    src="https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/nextjs-icon-2048x1234-pqycciiu.png"
    alt="logo nextjs"
    width="100"
    height="100"
  />
  <div>
    <h2 class="text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl text-center">
      Sample
    </h2>
    <p class="text-center pb-1 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 lg:text-xl sm:px-16 xl:px-48 ">
      Demo
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you are using **TailwindCSS** classes and you don't have to write extra CSS code!

Note: if you want them to be on the sides, use `justify-between` instead of `justify-center`.

I encourage you to improve your native CSS skills, especially FlexBox as [@Rounin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78241278/7918037), this will help you understand what these classes are doing.